# Parse - Facebook login via Facebook app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse SDK as my backend and I have also implemented the Facebook login, which works perfectly!! The thing is, when the user presses the FB login button and he's prompted to choose how to login, either type his credentials or use the fb app, if he chooses the latter, nothing happens!

Does anyone know how to enable the Facebook login through the Facebook app?

Comment: Difficult to comment if we cant see what you have tried or what your current login process looks like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to update the Facebook login SDK and put the items below, on my .plist file's `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`:

```
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not login with Facebook Native App. But you can change the `loginBehavior` to `systemAccount`. If the user registered their Facebook Information to their iPhone. `ParseFBSDK` can reach them.

You should add this line after your ParseFacebookUtils initialization

```
PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager().loginBehavior = .systemAccount
```

You can change your login behaviors like this.